# JS - Why isnt the second value in my "or" equation recognised

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to create a function that will move an png image either up, down, left or right by the user either pressing WASD or the Arrow Keys. At the moment i have figured out a way to move the item using WASD however when i introduce the "or" operand and use the Key.Code for the arrow keys the arrow keys aren't recognised even though it will still recognise WASD

```
<body>
<div class="scene">
  <div class="rocket">
    <img src="rocket.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    var rocket = document.querySelector(".rocket");
    let speed = 10;

     if (event.keyCode == (87 || 38) && rocket.offsetTop > 100) {
     rocket.style.top = `${rocket.offsetTop - speed}px`;
     }
     if (event.key == "s" && rocket.offsetTop < window.innerHeight - 300) {
     rocket.style.top = `${rocket.offsetTop + speed}px`;
     }
     if (event.key == "a" && rocket.offsetLeft > 50) {
     rocket.style.left = `${rocket.offsetLeft - speed}px`;
     }
     if (event.key == "d" && rocket.offsetLeft < window.innerWidth - 125) {
     rocket.style.left = `${rocket.offsetLeft + speed}px`;
     }
     if (event.key == " " && rocket.offsetTop > 100) {
     rocket.style.top = `${rocket.offsetTop - 200}px`;
     }
     console.log(event.keyCode);
     });
```

Comment: What happens if you try it like this: `if ((event.keyCode == 87 || event.keyCode == 38) && rocket.offsetTop > 100)`?
EDIT: I also see that in your function you pass `e`, not `event`. So try `e.keyCode` in stead of `event.keyCode`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression:

```
87 || 38
```

Evaluates to `87`.  Every time.  Which means this expression:

```
event.keyCode == (87 || 38)
```

Compares the value to `87`.  Every time.

Don't think of these logical conditions as intuitive human language.  They need to be built as individual logical expressions which individually evaluate to a value.  What you're looking for is this:

```
(event.keyCode == 87 || event.keyCode == 38)
```

Comment: Ahhh of course!!! Thank you! Sometimes its the simple things

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
 if ((event.keyCode == 87 || event.keyCode == 38)  && rocket.offsetTop > 100)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR